# Can H2 heading visually look like H1 and vice versa according to WCAG rules?

Tags: html, css, wcag2.0

I am into Accessibility testing. In my case we have Two headings

```
<h1 class="CssPropertywithSmallFontSize">Heading One</h1>
<h2 class="CssPropertywithBiggerFontSize">Heading Two</h2>
```

Visually H1 looks smaller than H2 due to the CSS property added to it.
Is such a scenario acceptable based on WCAG 2.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

WCAG Guidelines related to headings are available here: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H42.html

From what I understand, as long as you're appropriately moving from H1-H2-H3... and so forth WCAG has no concern for the font sizes or differences between them. Generally, due to the function of headings, you will be styling a page to show headings steadily decreasing in size. If the style of your page lends to having these sizes be mix-matched that's your prerogative.

I would, however, recommend revisiting the way your page is designed to make sure this is the best option.